# JavaScript lookup value from array, replace with next index

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, tagname

I have a string variable which is generated like this

```
domNodes += '<a href="javascript: void(0);" data-role="node_jump" data-node="'+this.tagName.toLowerCase()+'">'+this.tagName + "</a>" + " &raquo; ";
```

I also have an array which houses a 2D array with a string to lookup and a string to replace it with:

```
var replaceTags = [["i", "em"], ["b", "strong"]];
```

If `this.tagName` == `i` then replace with `em` the same for `b` and `strong`.

I know this is simple because I've done it before, I just can't remember how :(

Comment: Something along the lines of `text.split(this.tagName).join(this.tagToReplaceWith)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Nw45Y/

```
var replaceTags = [["i", "em"], ["b", "strong"]];
var tn = this.tagName;
for (var i =0; i < replaceTags.length; i++) {
    tn = tn.replace(new RegExp(replaceTags[i][0], 'g'),replaceTags[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this:

```
function replaced(x) {
    var replaceTags = [["i", "em"], ["b", "strong"]];
    for(var i = 0; i < replaceTags.length; i++) {
        if(replaceTags[i][0] === x) return replaceTags[i][1];
    }
    return x;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
data-node="'+replaced(this.tagName.toLowerCase())+'"
```